# Preposition for the verb "unassign"

Tags: prepositions

If I say something like this:

I will assign this task ***to*** this user.

How do I say the same with the verb "unassign", meaning that I want to remove the assignment of that task to that user?
What seems the most logical at the moment is:

I will unassign this task ***from*** this user.

Comment: Since the verb "unassign" is a specialized word for computer science, I would suggest looking in computer science papers to find out what the usage has been.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. Have you tried to google this verb and see how it is used in sentences? Note that if you can find the answer to your question in dictionaries, it may be closed as such.

Comment: Tried Googling but without this specific sentence structure. Tried searching here as well, but to no avail.

Comment: I would automatically use "unassign a task **from** a user". Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156986/if-i-assign-someone-a-task-what-is-the-correct-verb-for-unassigning-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of unassign is logically sound but it's not technically correct. To be 'unassigned' is to be in a state of having nothing assigned to you, not the past tense of unassigning. The word 'unassign' is a computing term that hasn't really made it into common language. In fact it doesn't exist in [Merriam-Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassign) at all.

If you look up the synonyms and antonyms of assign you can find more useful terms that may fit the situation more easily.

Comment: Good answer.  It's odd that there is not a good antonym for *assign*.  When I tried to find an acceptable way to say ***unassign** from* nothing came to mind.  I would probably say unassign, to be honest.  If I was deliberately trying to avoid using the non-word *unassign* I would most likely say.  *I am going to assign Task A to Rita and take Tom off Task A.*  But you won't find *Take Off* listed as an antonym anywhere.

Comment: Most English words don't have antonyms. Some few do, and that gives the impression that every word does. Think about it - what is the antonym of _tower_? Dome? Pit? Lawn? none of them are a tower, after all. Why aren't they antonyms? There's too many ways to be opposed.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would argue that verbs and adjectives often have them. What you have given as an example is being used as a noun.

Comment: Simple physical adjectives like _tall_ often have them, yes. But how about _run, talk, striped, purple,_ or _fuzzy_? Any time one gets beyond simple sentences and third-grade vocabulary, somehow it doesn't work well any more. [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is an extremely complex phenomenon.

Comment: @EllieK, I don't think they could ever be written as opposites because they have different objects (the task for one, and the person for the other)

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine  I disagree.  I can assign Rita to the task.  I can also assign the task to Rita.  They cannot be written as opposites because they are not opposites.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said 'listed' rather than written — you said you'd use 'take off', but you'd never see it listed as an antonym. I was agreeing, and saying that the other issue with listing them as opposites is the way you'd written them they have different objects. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered the problem with the word "assign". :) If you can, choose a different verb that has a direct antonym, especially if you're writing user-facing text. However, if you're stuck with "assign", then try "remove...from". It's not a perfect antonym, but it does capture the action of taking away a task that was "given" to the user.